# Android - start microphone from a foreground service whilst the app is not in focus

Tags: android

Can I start the microphone from a foreground service that isn't in the foreground?
I am new to Android Dev.

I have created a foreground service that is started by pressing a button inside the app's main activity.

It can start the microphone whilst the app is in focus, but I can't get it to record when the app is not in focus, even though the foreground service is still running. Is there a way to start the microphone whilst the main activity is not in focus?

Comment: you are literally not respecting the user privacy like that. And to answer your question no you can't

Comment: I am not doing anything malicious, I am trying to have an AI-backed conversation with the user which I play audio, then listen, then respond with audio, then listen etc.
I am developing an app that plays interactive stories to users, but the moment that the screen is not in focus I am not able to start the microphone. Is there no other way around this?

Comment: I see. add the code and check these out 
https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/foreground-services#background-start-restriction-exemptions

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/foreground-services